# null value not updating in Semantic react Input field

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui-react

I am creating a form with React Semantic UI. Here is the Form.

```
<Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <Form.Group>
            <Form.Input
              placeholder="Name"
              name="name"
              value={name}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
            <Form.Input
              placeholder="Email"
              name="email"
              value={email}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
            <br />
            <Form.Button content="Submit" />
          </Form.Group>
        </Form>
```

Here is the submit action method

```
handleSubmit = () => {
    const { name, email } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      submittedName: name,
      submittedEmail: email,
      name: null,
      email: null
    });
  };
```

After saving the input field `values` into `submitted values`, i am trying to update `name` and `email` to null. The value is updating to null but the Input box is still showing the typed value only.

if I am updating value as `""` (like below), it's updating fine.

```
handleSubmit = () => {
    const { name, email } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      submittedName: name,
      submittedEmail: email,
      name: "",
      email: ""
    });
  };
```

But it's not working for `null` value alone. Any leads here.
Sample codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/nullvalueissue-h3sv9?file=/example.js:289-476

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The examples in the docs all reset using `""` but if for some reason you need to use `null` then just set the value conditionally: `value={email ? email : ""}`

Edited sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/nullvalueissue-forked-hllno

Answer (score 0):

I'm not good with class component, but I do
`value={form.email || ""}` with

```
    setForm({ ...form, [name]: value });
  };
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).